# Is System.out buffered or unbuffered?

Tags: java

Is `System.out` buffered or unbuffered?

I read this is an object of `InputStream` and `PrinterStream` is the type of object referenced by `System.out`.

And they Both are Unbuffered so Why `println()` flushes the unbuffered...is it possible to flush unbuffered and I have read they are written immediately.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html you can visit this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is the "standard" output. On most [operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) that terminal io is buffered, and paging is supported.

From the Javadoc,

> The "standard" output stream. This stream is already open and ready to accept output data. Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user.

Comment: Ok that's right System.out is buffered...
But i want to also want to know what do you mean by a buffered input stream?

Comment: Consider a pipe. One process writes, one process reads. But where did I mention a buffered input stream here? If you are reading standard in (or the output of another process), you must have an input stream to read from.

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html :

> Optionally, a `PrintStream` can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the `flush` method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the `println` methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte (`'\n'`) is written.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println prints the argument passed, into the System.out which is generally stdout.

```
System – is a final class and cannot be inherited. As per javadoc, “…Among the facilities provided by the System class are standard input, standard output, and error output streams; access to externally defined properties and environment variables; a means of loading files and libraries; and a utility method for quickly copying a portion of an array…”
out – is a static member field of System class and is of type PrintStream. Its access specifiers are public final. This gets instantiated during startup and gets mapped with standard output console of the host. This stream is open by itself immediately after its instantiation and ready to accept data.
println – println prints the argument passed to the standard console and a newline. There are multiple println methods with different arguments (overloading). Every println makes a call to print method and adds a newline. print calls write() and the story goes on like that.
```