# Java: Printing to screen is delayed

Tags: java, java-threads, system.out

So I have a function that is supposed to print out text like it is being typed onto the screen.

I tried setting and getting the time it took to print to the screen using System.nanoTime(), and removing that from Thread.sleep, but it was still not smooth.

I would like for each letter to be printed and take roughly the same amount of time, instead of jerking back and forth between letters like it currently does.

```
public static void slow_print(String to_print) {
    long time_between = 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < to_print.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(to_print.charAt(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time_between);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException event) {
            System.out.println("Not supposed to happen");
        }

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You may need to `flush` the stream. Additionally, console output tends to be somewhat unreliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is bufferized. To flush buffer you need to call `flush` or include `\n` into your string.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401467/is-system-out-buffered-or-unbuffered for further reading on this topic.

Comment: Note that you can print and flush in a one-liner, `System.out.append(to_print.charAt(i)).flush();`. If there’s still a delay, it might be connected with the receiving terminal, whose behavior is entirely out of your control. But you may try different terminals, run in a native console or within your IDE, to compare the behavior, to check whether this could be the cause.